# Can I disable "Open with Access" option in the ribbon for a list? SP2010

Tags: list, permissions, custom-list

Here is why: I have a SP2010 list with permissions set so that default is 'view only' and a limited group has 'contribute' perms.

If I log in with a non-priviledged account, and view the list,there is no 'Edit List' option available in the Ribbon as desired. But, in the Ribbon, there is **Connect & Export > Open with Access**. If I do this, I then find I have full CRUD rights and can wreak havoc on the list while within Access, and the changes do affect the list.

If I log in as an admin, and check permissions on the list for that non-priviledged account, I get back 'View Only'. In **Site Settings > Site Admin > Site libraries & lists > (list) > Advanced Settings**, the list is set to "Create & Edit Access : None". So from what I can tell, I've got things locked down as intended. Which leads me to believe that Access access full-CRUD-rights is a product bug or, far more likely, I'm missing something obvious. I figure if it's a bug it'll never get fixed soon, but if I can disable that "Open with Access" option in that Ribbon, that'll work.

Is there a way to disable that 'Open with Access' option in the Ribbon?

(Update a couple hours later)  I can use CSS rules to hide the items in the ribbon, but to be sure that really isn't much of a solution. Ref. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/bc921475-504d-4443-9388-828373e2582d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alan,

Hiding a ribbon item with css is no problem and can be considered as a solution, but if you are looking for more optimal solution, you can create a Visual Web Part and on the list form just drop the webpart, in webpart PageLoad method, write following:

```
SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
ribbon.TrimById("Ribbon.List.Actions.OpenWithAccess");
```

You can trim/disable the ribbon item by control id, and here is the list of all control id's in ribbon:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543(en-us,office.14).aspx

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the solution, and I thank you for your answer. I must say, though, in any other universe, nobody would accept using a css hide as a legitimate means of limiting user access to a potentially disastarous function. It's just The SharePoint Way, I guess ...

Comment: You are most welcome :)